# Debugging JavaScript in PhpStorm without static html

Tags: javascript, debugging, phpstorm

Let's consider `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` is in static `page.html`, which is served by a webserver as `GET /page.html`.

PhpStrom's debugger easily infers location of `script.js` in the file system. The only hint IDE needs--and usually sets it automatically--is where webserver's public folder resides. URL of `script.js` is provided by JetBrains IDE browser extension. Debugging is easy as a pie. Both local and remote modes work.

Then, we have the same `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` in the output of a php script, which is served as `GET /page`.

Console output is still visible in IDE, so browser extension works. But debugger doesn't break at breakpoints. The only reason, I guess, is mappings. IDE doesn't automatically map URLs to paths, but I can map manually:

- `http://my.app/` => webserver's public folder (say, `D:/My/public`)
- `http://my.app/js/` => `D:/My/public/js/`
- `http://my.app/js/script.js` => `D:/My/public/js/script.js`

The only URL I can't map to file or folder is, for obvious reasons, `http://my.app/page`.

I can't see any crucial difference between the two cases, which might break debugging. So, I suspect it's my fault. What should be done to workaround the problem?

Windows 7, PhpStorm 9, Chrome 46, JetBrains IDE support 2.08, Laravel 5.1, Homestead VM.